# Can I marry my mother's cousin brother is it acceptable in islam

Tags: nikah

As I am willing to marry my mother's cousin brother is it acceptable  in islam

Comment: Shouldn't the brother of your mothers cousin be her cousin too?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The cousin of your mother is not her mahram. So ofcourse, he is not your mahram and you can marry him.
But that might change if you were breast fed by the mother of whom you want to marry or if he was breast fed by your mother. Or if there is any other breastfeeding that has taken place which makes him your mahram.